# PayPal hosted button parameters for IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Can I pass parameters with hosted buttons to identify the buyer/transaction/item/*, which I'll be able to process in the IPN notification handler? Or must I not use hosted buttons for this?
I couldn't find a clear authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

- You already *have* to pass paramaters to identify the item.
- You can pass an invoice number to identity the transaction.
- You can pass one other item of data which will be returned to you in the IPN, via the `custom` parameter.